# CSS, error parsing file 'text-shadow', expected series of <size>

Tags: css

I'm having this error:

```
WARNING: CSS Error parsing file:/Users/Mark/IdeaProjects/P1/target/classes/homepage.css: expected series of <size> while parsing '-text-shadow' at [116,18]
```

This is what i wrote:

```
.titled-pane {
    -fx-background-color: #3796a7;
    -fx-alignment: center;
    -fx-background-color: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #25bcbf, #3796a7);
    -fx-font-size: 14pt;
    -fx-text-fill: white;
    -text-shadow: 2px 2px 8px #ff0000;
 }
```

I found the 'text-shadow' code on the internet, but apparently there's some syntax error i cannot understand. I tried removing the '-' at the beginning, deleting '8px' since it's optional, but still nothing. Any help?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I know this is a bot, but what other code should i provide? lol